# List of JDBC drivers for SQL Server 2008 (comparison)

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc, jtds

I am in the process of evaluating a whole whack of JDBC drivers, specifically to use with SQL Server 2008 with Windows authentication. I gathered a list of ones that I found and have listed them below.

### My question is, are there any other JDBC drivers that are compatible with SQL Server 2008 that I should also look into reviewing?

1. **Microsoft JDBC driver**

   **URL**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724

   **Pros**: Official Microsoft JDBC driver for SQL Server 2008! Based on the JNetDirect JSQLConnect driver v3 as it was purchased by Microsoft a few years ago and they have been building on top of it since. I was told this by JNetDirect JSQLConnect's support.

   **Cons**: Seems to have a lot of connectivity/stability issues, don't believe me, just Google about it :). Doesn't have a way of disabling statement preparation/pooling which is something I am looking for.

   **JDBC compliance**: Claims to be be JDBC 4.0 compliant although many methods throw UnimplementedException!!!!

   **JDBC Type**: 4

   **Price**: Free
2. **Progress DataDirect**

   **URL**: http://www.datadirect.com/index.html

   **Pros**: Claims to be top class, used by numerous applications like Informatica, etc and the company is been around for ages! Have quick support - I have dealt with them briefly.

   **Cons**: ?

   **JDBC compliance**: Claims to be be JDBC 4.0 compliant

   **JDBC Type**: 5

   **Price**: Not free
3. **JTDS**

   **URL**: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

   **Pros**: Much faster than the official Microsoft JDBC driver. Has a way of disabling prepared statements.

   **Cons**: ?

   **JDBC compliance**: JDBC 3.0 compliant only. This is a deal breaker for me because important methods like .validate() and .isClosed() aren't supported because these are JDBC 4.0 methods.

   **JDBC Type**: 4

   **Price**: Free - Open Source
4. **INET Merlia**

   **URL**: http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/jdbc-driver/ms-sql/merlia

   **Pros**: Much faster than the official Microsoft JDBC driver. Has a way to disable prepared statements.

   **Cons**: ?

   **JDBC compliance**: Claims to be be JDBC 3.0/4.0 compliant

   **JDBC Type**: 4

   **Price**: Not free
5. **JNetDirect JSQLConnect**

   **URL**: http://www.jnetdirect.com/products/jsqlconnect.html

   **Pros**: Much faster than the official Microsoft JDBC driver. Has a way to disable prepared statements

   **Cons**: ?

   **JDBC compliance**: Claims to be be JDBC 3.0/4.0 compliant

   **JDBC Type**: 4

   **Price**:  Free for a single user with only 1 database connection.

*If you can keep your comments clean, I'll happily update this post with any others.*

Comment: Do you have a hard requirement to deploy SQL Server? Otherwise you wouldn't evaluate drivers.

Comment: @Michael-O, yes actually. I have to work with the existing database and the option to switch to another database system isn't something that they are willing to consider at this point. So unfortunately, I still have to evaluate drivers for SQL Server.

Comment: @BenBrunk, couldn't agree with you more. I was shocked when 4 people voted to close it within minutes of it being posted... made no sense then, still makes no sense today.

Comment: I suspect the reason this question was closed was because it is not a question that has a specific answer. For comparison/list questions of this nature, answering "which should I use" is subjective depending on the project, and no answers given would be appropriate for all situations. Questions of this nature are expressly called out in the FAQ as [out of scope](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: This is probably better suited to ServerFault.