# Java with SQL Server driver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I'm looking for good and free SQL server driver.
Currently I'm using jtds, but it's old and I have some issues with it.
SQL Server is 2014.

I found a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943553/list-of-jdbc-drivers-for-sql-server-2008-comparison) but my problem that it's outdated.
Tried using sqljdbc4, but we had too many problems with it.

Can you please suggest a decent driver with good performance and
low bug count.
I prefer a free license, but perpetual will be fine too.
Thanks.

Comment: What issues do you have with Microsoft JDBC driver? Did you check for latest updates (Version 4.2) ?

Comment: Some blobs were not working well, and I saw that people report poor performance. I saw that Microsoft released 6 (previews)

Answer (score 0):

sqljdbc4 is good but have a some problems, you can try with new version.

I'm using jtds (I use Sql Server 2014, with JDK 7).

This is the POM configuration

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Have you had some finalizing issues with it? or any Memory leak?
I tried 250 pool size and it had a memory leak.

Comment: Hi, no problem with memory leak. Pool size to 250 is not enough to define the root of your issue.