# camel-sql issue (different sql server versions)

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-camel, camel-sql

I have a basic camel route (running in karaf) this route returns a list of ID's from a SQL table, when connected to a SQL server 2012 the route works as expected,

**Route:**

```
       private static final String GET_PRODUCTS_QUERY = "select PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_DESC from CO_PROD";

       from("direct-vm:sqlRoute").routeId("testSQL")
        .streamCaching()
        .to(String.format("sql:%s?dataSource=sqlDataSource", GET_PRODUCTS_QUERY))
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "SQL response = ${body}");
```

**blueprint.xml**

```
<reference id="sqlDataSource"  filter="(osgi.jndi.service.name=sqlDataSource)" interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

<bean id="sqlComponent" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="sqlDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

When connected to SQL 2008 (this has the same table / data) i get the below error from the same route:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-2BJK8S2-0119-1583263311016-6-2]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1846)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:385)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:64)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmProcessor.process(DirectVmProcessor.java:57)
    at org.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmBlockingProducer.process(DirectVmBlockingProducer.java:53)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet.doService(CamelContinuationServlet.java:215)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:78)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRErrorListener
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerParameterMetaData.<init>(SQLServerParameterMetaData.java:347)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:3103)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:3114)
    at org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlProducer$2.doInPreparedStatement(SqlProducer.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlProducer$2.doInPreparedStatement(SqlProducer.java:116)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617)
    at org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlProducer.process(SqlProducer.java:116)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRErrorListener not found by com.microsoft.sqlserver.mssql-jdbc [47]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1639)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 52 more
```

If i switch to the below jdbc connection style it works with SQL server 2008:

```
    from("direct-vm:sqlRoute").routeId("testSQL")
    .streamCaching()
    .setBody(simple("select PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_DESC from CO_PROD",String.class))
    .to("jdbc:sqldataSource")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "SQL response = ${body}");
```

Does camel-sql only work with some versions of SQL server ?

Is there a way to log the endpoint / connection information sent in the .to ?

Can anyone help me understand why the initial route doesnt work with SQL 2008 but the same route connected to SQL 2012 works fine?

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRErrorListener not found by
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.mssql-jdbc

Maybe you need to try another jdbc driver, for example 
[List of JDBC drivers for SQL Server 2008 (comparison)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943553/list-of-jdbc-drivers-for-sql-server-2008-comparison)